# Installed Metasploit but it's not working!

Tags: 12.04

I have already semi-successfully installed the Metasploit Framework, but when I attempt to run the Metasploit console (msfconsole) it returns with the error:

```
/usr/local/bin/msfconsole:23:in `require': no such file to load -- /usr/local
/bin/config/boot (LoadError) from /usr/local/bin/msfconsole:23
```

I have been trying to fix this and searching on the web for days with no success. It's starting to get really frustrating.

Comment: Possibly something to do with ruby: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896485/no-such-file-to-load-rubygems-loaderror

Comment: @Paul Please, don't write your solution on the *question*, take a time and write it as an *answer* instead. People doesn't look for solutions on a question but on the answer section.

Comment: I was also having the same problem Running as following worked for me ./msfconsole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Ubuntu 12.04 and Metasploit and made sure there was only 1 ruby version (ruby-core). I started it up and it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

They broke it for modern versions of ruby in [commit 149c3ecc63bfe8bb261b47ccc783cd9f728692e5](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/commit/149c3ecc63bfe8bb261b47ccc783cd9f728692e5#diff-3a1a8688af4e7a3b333ebf1ca027af3d). My understanding is it has to do with changes to how ruby handles its path and loading requires.

A quick and dirty hack until they fix it upstream:

```
diff --git a/msfconsole b/msfconsole
index 9dee479..c3769bb 100755
--- a/msfconsole
+++ b/msfconsole
@@ -20,7 +20,8 @@ require 'pathname'
 #

 # @see https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.17/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/script/rails#L3-L5
-require Pathname.new(__FILE__).expand_path.parent.join('config', 'boot')
+#require Pathname.new(__FILE__).expand_path.parent.join('config', 'boot')
+require_relative 'config/boot'
 require 'metasploit/framework/command/console'

 Metasploit::Framework::Command::Console.start
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered by OP in question.

> It wasn't something to do with ruby. I opened up the msfconsole file and there was an invalid 'require' path.